# Get user's instagram likes

Tags: python, json, instagram

I've authenticated my personal account:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/liked?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

But it returns this:

```
{
pagination: { },
meta: {
code: 200
},
data: [ ]
}
```

The 200 code is supposedly a success, and I've liked 3 images, in the past 5 months, but they are not showing up in the data set. Why?

I also have the `likes` scope authorized. Not sure if that's necessary though?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your API call is correct and as you noted you're not getting any errors. The problem is likely the data you are expecting isn't there. Notice in the [documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_feed_liked) for that API method that it says

> Get the list of recent media liked by the owner of the access_token.

I suspect that either your data is too old (you said the past 5 months) and this may not fall under "recent media liked". Alternatively perhaps you are looking at a different user than you thought etc...

The `likes` scope is not necessary. You only need `public_content` scope for this API method.